# UITextField in UITableViewCell no keyboard on iPad but iPhone ok

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a tableView that has several table cells with TextFields as subviews

```
self.cellFirstName = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
self.tfFirstName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:Field1Frame];
self.tfFirstName.tag = 1;
self.tfFirstName.delegate = self;
self.tfFirstName.placeholder = @"First Name";
[self.cellFirstName addSubview:self.tfFirstName];
```

...

```
if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell =  self.cellFirstName;
}
```

the keyboard does not pop up when you touch the textField on a real iPad or click on the the TextField on a iPad simulator.
Works find on real and sim iPhone.

Somehow I can't do anything to make the keyboard pop up.

If I set one of the textFields as 1st responder then a keyboard shows up,
but when I dismiss the keyboard and hit any of the textFields - nothing - no keyboard.

clicking or touching the textFields just turns them blue.

I even copied the iPhone storyboard to iPad
and
changed targetRuntime to "iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"
still same results.

here is the hack I'm using to get this to work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        [self.tfFirstName becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 1) {
        [self.tfLastName becomeFirstResponder];
    } ...
```

I would rather understand what is keeping the keyboard from popping up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some special code for `iPad` , i'm thinking maybe you have set the `tfFirstName.userInteraction = NO;` and/or `tfFirstName.enabled = NO;` or one of the `delegate` methods to return `NO` when the device is `iPad`. Check those please.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, wouldn't your suggestions have the opposite effect (I want interaction, I want a keyboard), I tried all combos of setting userIneraction and enabled to NO and had no effect.  Are you aware of any iPad-isms which  is causing this?  also, which delegate methods are you referring to.  Again, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: you missunderstood , i said that you must check if you set the interaction to NO because is supossed to be YES.

Comment: In my earlier attempts to find the problem I did nslog those values and they came out YES, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: can you share the project so i can try it out?

Comment: If this were my own little project then I would but this is an app that a client paid me to create, when I get some time I will try to recreate the condition with a simple project and contact you directly.